# The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.ReadJSONResult, int, List<BeerData>) is undefined

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-xml

I am trying to bind an Array list to my listView. I am having trouble understanding how I associate an objects value such as its name to the list item XML value that shows in the list.

trying to add items from my array list to the list view:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, beerList);

                    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

My R.layout.list_item file looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView android:id="@+id/itemName" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My full main file can be viewed here to see how I make my array list:

http://pastebin.com/yV1K8TN1

Comment: You are creating a <String> ArrayAdapter but passing it BeerData objects instead of Strings.

Comment: create array of string and pass it to adapter, or make custom adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, beerList);
```

To this:

```
 ArrayAdapter<BeerData> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<BeerData>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.list_item, beerList);
```

and make sure `BeerData` implements a `toString()` method you are happy with. If your row layout is not super simple you might be better off making your own custom `Adapter`.

Comment: I changed it and get this error:

ArrayAdapter<BeerData>(MainActivity.ReadJSONResult, int, List<BeerData>) is undefined

and added a toString method to BeerData which returned the beers name. I get this error:

Comment: I made an edit, you need to change the contructor to have `MainActivity.this`, otherwise `this` refers to `ReadJSONResult`, which the ArrayAdapter knows nothing about of course.

Comment: Made the change, no more errors but when I try an open my app it force closes immediately:

http://pastebin.com/YB6P5tPL

Comment: Since MainActivity extends ListActivity, your `activity_main.xml` *must* have a listview in it with the id `android:id="@android:id/list"`. Read up on it here (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Comment: That fixes errors and runs, but when I do my search my arraylist is not update with anything:

http://pastebin.com/nQvYPDyV

Comment: It's starting to feel like I am coding this for you :) I feel I've answered your question - good luck, maybe someone else can help.

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far! I will make a separate question for my new problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display beername to the listview u can use a Iterator interface and iterate the List to get List and pass this to arrayadapter

```
Iterator<BeerData> itr = beerList.iterator();
 List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
while(itr.hasNext()){
  lst.add(itr.next().getBeerName());
}

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, lst);
```